# PhpStorm background color line number

Tags: background-color, line-numbers, phpstorm, webstorm

How to change background color of left panel (where line numbers). I want set it to dark. Because I using dark theme, but it left panel looks ugly with it :(

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts` | `General` | `Gutter background`.

Comment: I can't :( 'Vote Up requires 15 reputation' :[

Answer (score 3):

File | Settings | IDE Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts | General | Gutter background.

Answer (score 2):

Use *action-search* and type in 'gutter background':

Mac: cmd-shift-a